# I want to deploy my php based web application with apache-ant. How can I do that?

Tags: ubuntu, php5, deployment, ant

I googled it. But unfortunately did not get the specific answer. I am a fan of command line and typing. So now, I want to deploy my php based web application with apache-ant. How can I do that? Also I want to practice these deployment in my local pc. Is it possible? Phing is there and what i heard phing works on the top of apache-ant for php application deployment. But I want to face the hassel and want to write in my own hand.

Comment: ANT can be used independent of the language you write your program. E.g. if you use Eclipse, you can write a project XML with tasks that copy your PHP files the way you need

Answer (score 0):

Although ant is written in Java, you can still use it to deploy PHP to directories. Take a look at [this page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html)